# SEO tags in Umbraco

Tags: model-view-controller, seo, umbraco, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to render a view in MVC using SEO metadata, but I want to render a title (using ViewBag.Title)for children if there is no SEO metadata for them.How it can be done. Now it displays the value of parent or in other words the title of the parent node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple answers posted on SO for this question and issue. You can check them here e.g.:

- [Umbraco 7 SEO tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890374/umbraco-7-seo-tags) with my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39890772/1029339
- [Render view in MVC for SEO in Umbraco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913062/render-view-in-mvc-for-seo-in-umbraco)

Basically - you need to create a doctype or add properties to your current one and use ability of rendering those properties from IPublishedContent model in Umbraco. There is no need to transfer them via ViewBag. You can also use a package doing this for you automatically.